# React custom Hook to return an object

Tags: reactjs

I want to return an object from a custom React Hook (**useMyHook**):

```
const [ obj, setState ] = useState({a: {}, b: false});
...
setState({a:{toy: "Buzz"}, b:true});
return {obj}
```

In the Function component:

```
const {a, b} = useMyHook();

useEffect(() => {   
      ...     
}, [a.toy])
```

Then, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toy' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return {obj}`

This causes you to return an object that looks like:

```
{
  obj: {
    a: { toy: "Buzz" },
    b: true,
  }
}
```

The outer object has no `a` property, just an `obj` property, so when you do `const {a, b} = useMyHook();`, `a` and `b` are undefined.

Instead, you apparently want to do `return obj;`